# Customizing "More" Tab Bar

Tags: iphone

I am using a tab bar (UITabBarController) on my app and I wish to customize the appearance of the table that appears when you click the more button.

My app customized with a background image on every page. But image is not displaying when i click more button.

Any ideas?

Comment: can't do anyhing without any code... :(

Comment: You don't need any code... This is an API issue... Not a code level issue...

Comment: Wow, actually it would be helpful to see what he's doing. It's only an API issue if he's really doing what he thinks he's doing. More likely is that he's doing something entirely different, and expecting it to work how he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a UINavigationController as the main VC of your app, and a UITabBarController as one of the VC's on its stack.

I believe Apple actively discourages people from doing this in their apps, and so do I. It is never done in the iOS itself, and I have never seen it in any third-party apps either, so users will probably be confused.

I think you should embed the UINavigationController inside the UITabBarController instead of the other way around, or you could just choose to use another way of showing what you want to show.

see [UITabBarController's 'More' navigation controller disappears under UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050739)

Answer (score 3):

If you're actually using `UINavigationController` embedded within a `UITabBarController` then the more item is a `UINavigationController` which exists as a property of your `UITabBarController` with the name `moreNavigationController`. You can manipulate it in methods of your `UITabBarController` just as you can any other `UINavigationController`.

HTH, Pedro :)