# UITabBarController's 'More' navigation controller disappears under UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a UITabBarController as well as a UINavigationController on my app.

In my UITabBarController I am using more than 5 items so I automatically get the 'More' item.
I've managed to add a saving procedure so the order of those items will be kept in case somebody changes the order etc.

With 'More' active I get the More navigation controller with the 'Edit' item positioned under my UINavigationController. Both navigation controller are visible. When I click on 'Edit though the More navigation controller disappears and seem to be hiding under my UINavigationController and therefore I can't see/use the 'Done' function to save my new order

What did I miss?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a `UINavigationController` as the main VC of your app, and a `UITabBarController` as one of the VC's on its stack.

I believe Apple actively discourages people from doing this in their apps, and so do I. It is never done in the iOS itself, and I have never seen it in any third-party apps either, so users will probably be confused.

I think you should embed the `UINavigationController` inside the `UITabBarController` instead of the other way around, or you could just choose to use another way of showing what you want to show.

Comment: Yep I know, in IB I could just drag the UINavigationController onto the UITabBarController. But I am creating my tabs programmatically. So how would I have to do that?

Comment: You can just add the `UINavigationController` to the `UITabBarController` via the `viewControllers` property or the `setViewControllers:animated:` method. Both take an `NSArray` of `UIViewController` s.

Comment: How would I add the UINavigationController?
 
[tabs setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aboutPerson,activities,bookmarks,whiteboard,colleagues,test,nil]];

Comment: `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController, anotherViewController, yourInstanceOfUINavigationController, nil]`

Answer (score 1):

I believe iOS does use both navigation controller and tab controller at the same time in their iPod app. The navigation controller takes you to the playing song and back and at the same time you have the tab controller when you select songs/albums/playlists etc. However, the navigation controller (or tab bar controller) seems to be custom made as it handles the More->Edit case by hiding the navigation bar underneath the Edit bar, which is not what the default UITabBarController does.

All in all, I see Apple is rather "creative" when it comes to UI design. For example, in the email app, "New" button is in the lower right corner (bottom bar) while in the SMS app the "New" button is in the upper right corner (navigation bar). I think they pretty much make custom UI to fit the individual needs of the app instead or rigidly following some consistent design.