# How Can i put more of 5 tabs in a Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

:D

i'm have a storyboard with a TabBarController but when i do the relationship with my others seven view controllers in mi tab bar appears a "more" Tab,  How can i put this seven tabs in one tabbar?

I´ll have to do manually? with a tabbarcontroller class? or implementing Tabbar Delegate in a uiviewcontroller, But i dont have any idea how to do this.

Thank You Soo much! 
Please Help Me.

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Apple actively discourages people from doing this in their apps, and so do I. It is never done in the iOS itself, and I have never seen it in any third-party apps either, so users will probably be confused.

> If you add more than five items to the viewControllers property, the
>   tab bar controller automatically inserts a special view controller
>   (called the More view controller) to handle the display of the
>   additional items. The More view controller provides a custom interface
>   that lists the additional view controllers in a table, which can
>   expand to accommodate any number of view controllers. The More view
>   controller cannot be customized or selected and does not appear in any
>   of the view controller lists managed by the tab bar controller. For
>   the most part, it appears automatically when it is needed and is
>   separate from your custom content. You can get a reference to it
>   though by accessing the moreNavigationController property of
>   UITabBarController.

Also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050739) for a possible workaround!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any open source custom UITabbarControler or can create your own.
As created in this open source code. [JFTabBarController a custom tabbar controller on Cocoa Controls](https://github.com/vermont42/JFATabBarController)

Answer (score 0):

Use private property called _customMaxItems on UITabBarController

Example:

```swift
final class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    private var customMaxItems: CGFloat {
        get {
            self.value(forKey: "_customMaxItems") as! CGFloat
        }

        set {
            self.setValue("_customMaxItems", forKey: key)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 

        self.customMaxItems = 10
    }

}
```